# Editing an imploded string

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, odbc, explode

I have an application in which I can assign task like cleaning the bathroom, washing the car and etc. I can assign a single task to let's say 3 to 4 persons using the code below

```
if (isset($_POST["btnassign"])){
$proj = $_REQUEST['projhid'];
$analyst = $_POST['analyst'];
$commaList = implode('| ', $analyst);
$queupass = "UPDATE projects set assignedto='$commaList', assignedby = '$uname' where projectname='$proj'";
$queresupass = odbc_exec($conn,$queupass);
$notifassign = "New Project Assignment";
$queprojgn = "INSERT INTO notification (notification,datetime,isread,createdby,createddate) 
                       values('$notifassign',GETDATE(),0,'$uname',GETDATE())";
$queprojresnot = odbc_exec($conn,$queprojgn);
echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "window.close();";
echo "</script>";
```

The code above is the assigning part which works great since I can assign a single task to number of workers using their ID.

Now, I also have an anchor tag which will show the workers assigned for that project like the one below which says ANALYST

[image]

If I click that anchor tag, I want to get the list of analyst assigned for that task, but remember that the assigned workers using their ID are imploded like to

1| 2| 3| 4| 5

I have this code below which explodes it

```
$que = "SELECT assignedto FROM PROJECTS where projectname = '$projname'";
$queres = odbc_exec($conn,$que);
$res = odbc_result($queres, 1);
$analysts = explode("| ", $res);
echo $analysts[0]; // piece1
echo $analysts[1]; // piece2
echo $analysts[2]; // piece1
echo $analysts[3]; // piece2
echo $analysts[4]; // piece1
echo $analysts[5]; // piece2
echo $analysts[6]; // piece1
echo $analysts[7]; // piece2
die();
```

which is eventually works but what I need is to explode it an place it in table that has a remove anchor tag like the one below, any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: as I understand, you need to edit the value of assigned_to in the database once user removes a worker.Correct?

Comment: Yes. So if the original assigned to is 1| 2| 3| 4| 5 and i want to remove lastname,Juan assuming that he takes the id of 3 then the assignedto will become 1| 2| 4| 5

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by:

1. Selecting the `assignedto` from the table like this

   `$que = "SELECT assignedto FROM PROJECTS where projectname = '$projname'";`
2. Exploding the string received:

   `$analysts = explode("| ", $res);`
3. Using [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the remove the desired worker:

   `$new_analysts = array_diff($analysts, $remove_worker_id);`
4. Imploding the new array to a pipe seperated string:
    `$result = implode("| ", $new_analysts);`

EDIT:

For creating the HTML table with the remove link,

```
$que = "SELECT assignedto FROM PROJECTS where projectname = '$projname'";
$queres = odbc_exec($conn,$que);
$res = odbc_result($queres, 1);
$analysts_arr = explode("| ", $res);

$analysts = implode(",", $analysts_arr);

$que2 = "SELECT [user_id, first name, last name] FROM [user table] where [user_id] IN '$analysts'";
$query = odbc_exec($conn,$que2);
$result = odbc_result_all($query);

foreach($result as $val){
   $user_id = $val['user_id'];
   $users[$user_id] = $val;
}
```

After this, all you have to do is iterate the `$analysts_arr` and create the HTML needed for the table.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: But how will I show it in table like the last photo on my original post?